# OnStop() is called after onStart()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, robospice

In my application I am using robospice. So in my BaseActivity a created spice manager:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(!spiceManager.isStarted()) {
            spiceManager.start(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (spiceManager.isStarted()) {
            spiceManager.shouldStop();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
```

But when I start new activity, in new activity is called onStart() before parent onStop() - so it disconnect the service. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Am not sure if i understood your question correctly. But if i did i guess you have problem as your BaseActivity onStop is called after you start new activity.

well in this case you can use  **onResume** and **onPause** instead of onStart and onStop.

```
@Override
     protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
         if(!spiceManager.isStarted()) {
             spiceManager.start(this);
         }
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         if (spiceManager.isStarted()) {
             spiceManager.shouldStop();
         }

     }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, onStart() of new activity is called before onStop() parent activity, so it disconnect the service

Comment: @Stepan so have tried using the onResume() and onPause()  instead of onStop() and onStart()?

Answer (score 0):

Just add some boolean flag and switch it before starting another activity. Also, change your onStop method to this:

```
protected void onStop() {
    if (spiceManager.isStarted() && !mIsStartedNewActivity) {
        spiceManager.shouldStop();
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```